# Google URL Shortener automatically visits my links on shortening

Tags: google-app-engine, google-url-shortener

When I use the google URL shortener to shorten some links, I see in the UserAgent logs that they are being automatically visited right on creation.

Can this be explained in any way?

Comment: Is it from Google?  If so, checking they are valid?

Comment: It is from google. Is this behaviour documented anywhere?

Comment: Only thing I saw was this: "Once created, your link won’t expire unless it has to be removed for spam, privacy, or legal reasons."  So maybe it's scanned after creation.

Comment: "Our spam detection algorithms are automated, and routinely disable 
suspicious goo.gl short URLs. We understand that our algorithms are 
not perfect and are continually working on refining them. " https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-url-shortener/scan/google-url-shortener/pemNrYhHZz8/B3tFEPLw88wJ

Answer (score 0):

Most probably visited in order to build the preview shown on every link.

Comment: How can you tell for sure?

Comment: I forgot to mention that we are using the API of the url shortner. Can this still be the case?

Comment: to be honest im not an expert, but Google always pays a visit in order to get some info regarding the final URL (including preview). I'm guessing using the API still triggers that visit.

Answer (score -2):

i think googlebot also crawls your links that's why you can see a visit in your analytics. to remove this types of problems you can use [www.shrinkurl.in](http://www.shrinkurl.in). A nice url shortener.